# SqlError: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_SiteUrlMap'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SiteUrlMap'.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, restore

Getting below error while performing Restore-SPSite:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint 'PK_SiteUrlMap'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.SiteUrlMap'. The duplicate key value is (0x, abc.pqr.com/xyz, 3).
>   The statement has been terminated.      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand
>   command, SqlInfoMessageEventHandler handler) 
>   ClientConnectionId:82c5ef0d-e19f-4075-a9c0-0b850cb17795  Error
>   Number:2627,State:1,Class:14

Comment: Does this apply: https://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-copying-host-named-site-collections-multiple-spsiteurls/

Comment: I already went through this link but it didn't help. Option 1 is not feasible for me. I am using option 2 but getting same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us what you want to achieve with your restore-operation. I assume you want to copy or rename an existing HostNamed SiteCollection (HNSC).

A HSNC [can have different URLs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/svarukala/2014/05/06/change-host-named-site-collection-url/) assigned with the [Set-SPSiteURL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/set-spsiteurl?view=sharepoint-ps) Command.

There are several possible solutions:

[**Option #1: remove all SPSiteUrls**](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-copying-host-named-site-collections-multiple-spsiteurls/)

The first option that you have is to remove all SPSiteUrls before performing the backup of the Site Collection. After having restored the site you would add the SPSiteUrls back and optionally would add some new SPSiteUrls to the copied Site Collection.

Although this approach is pretty straight-forward it has one serious disadvantage: by removing the additional SPSiteUrls from the original Site Collection you’re interrupting its operability and prevent some users from accessing it. And although this might be okay in some cases, there might be scenarios where this is simply not an option.

[**Option #2: remove all SPSiteUrls after the backup**](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-copying-host-named-site-collections-multiple-spsiteurls/)

An alternative approach would be to take a backup of the Site Collection, restore it in another Farm of exactly the same patch level, remove all SPSiteUrls there and then restore it back to the original Farm.

In this case no service interruption occurs in the original Site Collection. The only downside is the need for a separate Farm with exactly the same patch level as the original Farm where you can restore the Site Collection from the backup, remove all SPSiteUrls and create a new backup to restore to the original Farm.

[**Option #3: Directly rename the site without backup&restore**](https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=573)

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://portal.contoso.com/sites/foo
$uri = New-Object System.Uri("http://foo.contoso.com")
$site.Rename($uri)
```

To get 100% success I have to force the Content Database to refresh its site map with this:

```
((Get-SPSite http://foo.contoso.com).contentdatabase).RefreshSitesInConfigurationDatabase
```

and run an IISReset. The IISReset isn’t always necessary, but it’s good to plan for it.

Comment: Hi MHeld, Thanks for reply. My requirement is to take backup of site from prod and restore it to pre prod. I cant choose option 1 as I cant remove site URL from Prod. Currently I am using 2nd Option for this activity but facing same issue. Option 3 is not applicable for me.

Comment: The error should only happen, if you already have a HNSC with the same SiteURL. Does the site already exist in an older version in PreProd? You could also try to get more information by directly reading content of the affected "dbo.SiteUrlMap" table in SQL Server (SELECT * from dbo.SiteUrlMap). You can find it in the SharePoint Configuration Database. WARNING: Do not modify anything directly in the database! You will instantly lose support on your farm.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug to restore host name site collection , try to install security update to fix the problem :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3141486/ms17-002-description-of-the-security-update-for-sharepoint-server-2016 .